# Confusion about Definition of Manifold

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading Munkres' *Analysis on Manifolds*, and it defines manifold as below:
Let $k>0$. A $k$-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of class $C^r$ is a subspace $M$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ having the following property:
 For each $p\in M$, there is an open set $V$ of $M$ containing $p$, a set $U$ that is open in either $\mathbb{R}^k$ or $\mathbb{H}^k$ and a continuous map $\alpha$ :$U\rightarrow V$in a one-to-one fashion, such that:
(1) $\alpha$ is of class $C^r$.
(2) $\alpha^{-1}$: $V\rightarrow U$ is continuous.
(3) $D\alpha(x)$ has rank $k$ for each $x\in U$
The map $\alpha$ is called a coordinate patch on $M$ about $p$.

And following this definition, the book gives a theorem:
Let $M$ be a $k$-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$, of class $C^r$. Let $\alpha_0: U_o\rightarrow V_0$ and $\alpha_1: U_1\rightarrow V_1$ be coordinate patches on $M$, with $W = V_0\cap V_1$ non-empty. Let $W_i = \alpha^{-1}(W)$. Then the map $\alpha^{-1}\circ\alpha^{-0}: W_0\rightarrow W_1$ is of class $C^r$, and its derivative is non-singular.


The proof of theorem in the book begins with: It suffices to show that if $\alpha: U\rightarrow V$ is a coordinate patch on $M$, then $\alpha^{-1}: V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ is of class $C^r$, as a map of the subset $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Then if it can be proved that if $\alpha: U\rightarrow V$ is a coordinate patch on $M$, then $\alpha^{-1}: V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ is of class $C^r$, why in the definition it requires $\alpha^{-1}$ to be continuous? Isn't $\alpha^{-1}$ is also $C^r$, which is at least continuous?

Comment: Presumably, one needs the continuity of $\alpha^{-1}$ to obtain that result.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement (2), continuity of $\alpha^{-1}$, is necessary.

In Example 3 on page 198, Munkres constructs an $\alpha$ which satisfies all conditions but (2), showing that this condition is not implied by the others.
As you state, if $\alpha^{-1}\in C^r$, then (2) must hold.
Conversely, it is not always true that $\alpha^{-1}\in C^r$, if (2) is omitted.